# Python Beautifulsoup count

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML like

```
<ul><li class="active">Bitte Größe wählen</li><li class="disabled">
(EU 41 - US 8) </li><li class="">
EU 42 - US 8,5 </li><li class="">
EU 42,5 - US 9 </li><li class="">
EU 43 - US 9,5 </li><li class="disabled">
(EU 44 - US 10) </li><li class="disabled">
(EU 44,5 - US 10,5) </li><li class="disabled">
(EU 45 - US 11) </li><li class="">
EU 46 - US 12 </li></ul>
```

How can I count all the `<li>...</li>` inside of this this `<ul>.... </ul>`?

so the output should be 9 because there are 9 `<li>...</li>´s`

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: No, because I have no idea how, sorry, I am pretty new to beautifulsoup

Comment: `len(soup.find('ul').find_all('li'))`

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup basically gives the DOM in list form. As in [ul] where ul is another list [li, li, li, li etc...]. You can call len() on the inner list.